# How to get parent field values based on linked junction object

Tags: map, junction-object

I have 3 objects. Platform and documents are parent and junction platform is child.

```
Platform
Junction platform Doc (junction object)
documents
```

I need all the documents linked to the platform. For example If I use "platformId" as a key I need all the "List of documents" to that platform.

I have tried some thing like this:

```
   set<id>pltIds=new set<id>();
   for (Document_Access__c yLd:scope)
       {
       pltIds.add(yLd.Platform__c);
        }

   List<JunctionPlatformDoc__c> junctionplatformDoclist=[select id, Document__c,Platform__c from JunctionPlatformDoc__c where Platform__c in:pltIds];
   for(JunctionPlatformDoc__c juncDoc:junctionplatformDoclist){

   if(String.isNotBlank(juncDoc.Platform__c))
       {
         if(!mapPltDocs.containsKey(juncDoc.Platform__c)) {
            mapPltDocs.put(juncDoc.Platform__c,new List<Id>());
         }
        mapPltDocs.get(juncDoc.Platform__c).add(juncDoc.Document__c);
       }

   }
```

Here platform is a key and that key contain List of documentIds. I need platform and its list of documents values (entire object).Is it possible?

Iam using that logic in batch class:

```
 for (Document_Access__c yLd:scope)
    {
        if (yLd.Operation__c!='Delete' )
        {
           Id platformId = mapAcctPlatform.get(yLd.Id);
               List<Id> lstDocuments= mapPltDocs.get(platformId);  //instead of Ids I need list of documents
             if(lstDocuments!=null){ 

             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are doing an individual operation per Junction.  If so, you can just modify your query to include both objects on the Junction object by using `__r` instead of `__c` to specify a reference field:

```
List<JunctionPlatformDoc__c> junctions = 
    [select Document__r.Name, Platform__r.Name from JunctionPlatformDoc__c where Platform__c in :pltIds];
```

Note that this will pull down a full object into the `Document__r` and `Platform__r` fields on the `JunctionPlatformDoc__c` object.  This means that if you do need to group them by Platform, you can do this relatively easily by looping through:

```
Map<Id, List<Document__c>> docs = new Map<Id, List<Document__c>>();
for(JunctionPlatformDoc__c junction : junctions)
{
    if(!docs.containsKey(junction.Platform__c))
    {
        docs.put(junction.Platform__c, new List<Document__c>());
    }
    docs.get(junction.Platform__c).add(junction.Document__r);
}
```

Comment: suppose if i need document description, how to get it...doc.values() gives name,record type id for me..i have modified query as well   select Document__r.Name,Document__r.Description__c,Platform__r.Name from JunctionPlatformDoc__c

Comment: @AnnappaPH Assuming that's the right field name, it should work as you've typed it.  Have you tried debugging `docs.values()[0].Description__c`?

Comment: ya but itsnot working

Comment: Is your code running as `with sharing`?  If your query didn't select the field, you should get a QueryException if you try to access it without writing to it first.

Comment: its not able to get other values except name,,iam able to get record typeid,name...if I query other field also.Is it working for you???

Comment: @AnnappaPH You should try creating a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code, and if you still are seeing the issue with it post it to a new question.

Comment: I have tried itsnot working check this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/217289/how-to-get-all-other-details-of-parent-object-using-junction-object