# How to get all other details of parent object using Junction Object

Tags: map

I have 3 objects. Platform and documents are parent and junction platform is child.

```
Platform
Junction platform Doc (junction object)
documents
```

---

```
 List<JunctionPlatformDoc__c> junctions = [select Document__r.Name,Document__r.Description__c,Platform__r.Name from JunctionPlatformDoc__c ];
  Map<Id, List<Document__c>> docs = new Map<Id, List<Document__c>>();
 for(JunctionPlatformDoc__c junction : junctions)
  {
if(!docs.containsKey(junction.Platform__c))
{
    docs.put(junction.Platform__c, new List<Document__c>());
}
docs.get(junction.Platform__c).add(junction.Document__r);
}
system.debug(docs.values()[0]);
```

***Problem Facing:***

system.debug log show only Id,name and record type Id.Is it possible to access other Information of document.In my case iam trying to access "document description"
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if that field is not blank. When we run code in developer console `system.debug` hide blank fields to display more records and save some space. SO enter dummy data in few records to get the description in debug.

When you run this code in actual class and try to access the value you will always get expected result.

Comment: Why downvote? Atleast leave a comment.